# In R how to find the earliest day with a value >0

Tags: r, date, count, find

I have a data set with many countries, dates and values. I need to find the earliest day with the first positive (>0) value for each country. In the following example for Italy Day_Count should be 1 for date 2020-03-24, and it should continue increasing towards upward.

```
     Country.Region       Date Value
9638          Italy 2020-03-27 150
9639          Italy 2020-03-26 120
9640          Italy 2020-03-25 110
9641          Italy 2020-03-24 80
9642          Italy 2020-03-23 0
9643          Italy 2020-03-22 0
```

So my final data should look like this

```
     Country.Region       Date Value  Day_Count
9638          Italy 2020-03-27 150    4
9639          Italy 2020-03-26 120    3
9640          Italy 2020-03-25 110    2
9641          Italy 2020-03-24 80     1
9642          Italy 2020-03-23 0      0
9643          Italy 2020-03-22 0      0
```

Would anybody help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
transform(df, Day_Count = rev(cumsum(rev(Value) != 0)))
```

Output:

```
  Country.Region       Date Value Day_Count
1          Italy 2020-03-27   150         4
2          Italy 2020-03-26   120         3
3          Italy 2020-03-25   110         2
4          Italy 2020-03-24    80         1
5          Italy 2020-03-23     0         0
6          Italy 2020-03-22     0         0
```

Or for different countries:

```
transform(df, Day_Count = ave(Value, Country.Region, FUN = function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x) != 0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(Day_Count = rev(cumsum(rev(Value) != 0)))
```